Movie about a little girl trying to help everyone
It was an American family movie I guess and I watched it 4-5 years ago. I don't suppose it is a very mainstream movie. I remember it as being a very good lesson oriented film.
This movie was about a little girl who always tries to help her parents and everyone but always ends up messing things up for everyone. There was this one time she wanted to earn some cash for her parents or brother (dont remember) she tried to sell lemonade but ended up wrecking everything.
It was a very sunny and uplifting movie. However, I remember another scene from the movie which showed her dad and her as spending quality time. I'm sorry I know it all sounds vague.

Thank you for the extra information. Are you looking for Ramona and Beezus, where the little protagonist tries to help her family with a similar scheme?

Good catch, that definitely sounds like Ramona Quimby.

YEESSSSSSS!!!! :D :D it is indeed Ramona and Beezus , Thankyou!! :D

however, i'm surprised i didnt remember Selena Gomez in this :P

You're looking for Ramona and Beezus from 2010.

The adventurous and creative third-grader Ramona Quimby (Joey King) often finds herself in trouble at school and at home, usually with her friend and neighbor, Howie (Jason Spevack). When her father Robert (John Corbett) loses his job and the family falls into severe debt, Ramona tries to find ways to earn money, such as selling "delishus lemonade" and a $20 car wash, which end up backfiring in humorous ways, include embarrassing her older sister, Beatrice (Selena Gomez), in front of Beatrice's childhood friend and crush, the paperboy Henry Huggins (Hutch Dano), especially when Ramona refers to her sister by her family nickname, "Beezus."

It was based on Beverly Cleary's Ramona books. Here's the trailer:



